# How to explain such a big difference between AIC and BIC values (lmridge package R)?

Tags: aic, ridge-regression, bic

[image: AIC & BIC ridge model difference]

BIC has a log(N=114) = 2.05 penalty. So, why do i get this result???
Package name: lmridge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an inconsistency in the scaling of AIC and BIC in the package `lmridge`. The relevant function is `infocr.lmridge()`. In the AIC case this employs `n * log(x/n) + 2 * (y)` whereas in the BIC case `n * log(x) + y * log(n)` is used, where `x` is the residual sum of squares and `y` are the degrees of freedom. Of course, for model selection it does not matter whether the additional `log(n)` term is present or not. But it would certainly be more consistent if the same definition were employed within the package. I encourage you to contact the `lmridge` maintainer about this.

If you do, please also point out that the `infocr()` approach is somewhat non-standard. Providing `AIC()` and `BIC()` methods would be more common. Or, even better, providing `logLik()` and `nobs()` methods, then the default `AIC()` and `BIC()` would work automatically.

Final remark: $\log(114) = 4.736$ because the *natural* logarithm is employed in BIC and not the *common* logarithm with base 10 $\log_{10}(114) = 2.0569$.